# Ruby on rails save base64 to xlsx (or pdf or word) and save it with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, paperclip, xlsx

I have a `base64` like this which I have generated on-line.It's for an `xlsx` file. I want to decode it and save it in db with `paperclip` so I did this :

```
decoded_data = Base64.decode64(Base64)
data = StringIO.new(decoded_data)
data.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :content_type, :original_filename
end
data.content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Model.create(file: data)
```

it creates a file and saves it on database but the file is damaged. I've tried it for `image` with `image content type` and it's fine but for `pdf`,`word` and `xlsx` it's not fine . Do you have any clue ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, how do you know you have a valid xlsx there?

Comment: I had an xlsx file I convert it to base64 online and tried to decode with ruby and save it

Comment: Now do it locally, and compare the strings. Should be equal. Why the online part, again? Ruby is perfectly capable of doing base64 encoding.

Comment: I know. The strings are the same . The problem is the content type .

Comment: Well, this _is_ a valid mime type for xlsx. The error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. The problem was for the content type.When I tried to store the files through `rails_admin` the file_content_type was :

```
for xlsx file content_type = "application/zip"
for csv file content_type = "text/plain"
for pdf file content_type = "application/pdf"
for word file content_type = "application/zip"
for image file content_type = "image"
```

But when I was trying to store the base64 file the `content_type` was quite different as you see below:

```
for xlsx file content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
for csv file content_type = "text/plain"
for pdf file content_type = "application/pdf"
for word file content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
for image file content_type = "image/jpg"
```

So I replaced that correct type and the problem soveld.

```
decoded_data = Base64.decode64(modified_base64)
data = StringIO.new(decoded_data)
data.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :content_type, :original_filename
end
if params[:contentType] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" 
    @content_type = "application/zip"
elsif params[:contentType] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    @content_type = "application/zip"
elsif params[:contentType] == "text/plain" 
    @content_type = "text/plain" 
elsif params[:contentType] == "application/pdf"
    @content_type = "application/pdf"
elsif params[:contentType].include?('image')
    @content_type = "imgae"
end
data.content_type = @content_type
data.original_filename = params[:file_name]
```

And don't forget to set the file name, for example if the file is `xlsx` you can name it as `sample.xlsx` that's a big deal.